# SetWindowsHookEx not working when I call it in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, setwindowshookex

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //intLLKey = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]).ToInt32(), 0);
    // it's working, but I wanna to call it in another thread 

    // not working
    new TaskFactory().StartNew(() =>
    {
        intLLKey = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]).ToInt32(), 0);
    });
}

[DllImport("user32", EntryPoint = "SetWindowsHookExA", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProcDelegate lpfn, int hMod, int dwThreadId);
public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
public int LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, int wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam)
{
    ...
}
```

I don't know why and I really wanna call it in another thread with some reason